# adding a #define through Cmake not working at compilation

Tags: c++, cmake, c-preprocessor

I have a certain file, a.hpp, of the following structure:

```
#ifndef HEADER
#define HEADER

#ifdef FLAG
namespace Foo {
   void somefunc();
}
#endif // FLAG

#endif // HEADER
```

I would like to include the file in another file, b.hpp, and not provide the #define FLAG
in that file, but rather provide it using the Cmake file.

the a.hpp file is a part of an external library called Utils, and is added via an ExternalProject_Add command like this:

```
target_link_libraries(Proj Proj/Lib/LibUtils.a)
ExternalProject_Add(Utils
   GIT_REPOSITORY http://somerepo
   GIT_TAG master
   CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=Proj/Lib -DFLAG
)
ExternalProject_Get_Property (Utils SOURCE_DIR)
target_include_directories(Proj PRIVATE ${SOURCE_DIR}/Inc)
```

in the Utils' Cmake file the following piece of code appears:

```
if (DEFINED FLAG)
   add_compile_options(-DFLAG)
endif(DEFINED FLAG)
```

I've tried adding the -DFLAG to the cmake args (as seen above),
i've tried adding add_definitions, target_compile_definitions, add_compile_definitions to the top of the a.hpp Cmake File but i still get a 'someFunc' is not a member of 'Foo'.

Comment: What if you say `-DFLAG=1`?

Comment: `ExternalProject_Add` makes the `Utils` project to be configured and built **separately** from the main one. That is, CMake commands inside `Utils` project has no effect on the main project. If you want to configure `Utils` project along with the main one, then use FetchContent instead of ExternalProject.

Comment: you can do `CMAKE_ARGS "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-DFLAG"` if you want

Comment: @KamilCuk unfortunately not working

Comment: @JohnZwinck also not working unfortunately..

Comment: @Tsyvarev will update if it worked.